# How can I format a us Currency without rounding off after decimal point in excel?

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel, currency, number-formatting

I am trying to export a money column into excel. The NumberFormat.Format is rounding Off the decimals by default. I have to show the decimals without rounding them.

My current code is

```
workSheet.Cell(i + 1, j + 1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "$ #,##0.00"
workSheet.Cell(i + 1, j + 1).DataType = XLDataType.Number
```

> value 50828.49 is displaying as $50,828.00 but i need to show as such $50,828.49

tried quite lot of suggestions in here.

**UPDATE**
In my code i was having convert.ToInt32 before the formatting. So it was call that's doing the rounding. i removed it and it works fine.

```
workSheet.Cell(i + 1, j + 1).Value = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cell(i + 1, j + 1).Value)
```

Comment: Have you checked the value that is passed to the VBA code? and the value actually in the cell?

Comment: @AJD The value that is getting passed is  50828.49 . but after it goes to the line workSheet.Cell(i + 1, j + 1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "$ #,##0.00". the after decimal value is getting rounded

Comment: OK, glad you found the issue and solved the problem.  In this case it is a problem that cannot be replicated - because your code was doing exactly as it was told! I am going to flag this as now off-topic as a problem that cannot be replicated.